# How to display my Inputted Text from the other class

Tags: java, android, eclipse

This is my Input Edit Text class

```
package com.example.websocketclient;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

EditText name;
Button enter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        enter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextdname);
                String dname = name.getText().toString();
                sendname(dname);                
            }
        });

    }

    public void sendname(String dname) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this,Chatroom.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("myname", dname);
        i.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(i);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

This is my display the EditText to TextView class

```
package com.example.websocketclient;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Chatroom extends Activity {

    TextView uname;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chatroom);

        uname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewmynam);

        //kuha  
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String urname = bundle.getString("myname");
        uname.setText(urname);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.chatroom, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

When i run it.. it says Unfortunately, then it will close..
I would like to pass a data from -> EditText to my other class to my display class -> TextView.

Comment: You just forgot to `initialize` your `enter` `Button` on `onCreate()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Along with ρяσѕρєя K answer, for passing the value you, since you are passing only one String, you can just use:

```
 intent.putExtra("value","key");
```

and while getting,

```
String value= getIntent.getStringExtra("key","default_value");
```

Answer (score 0):

> it says Unfortunately, then it will close..

Because you are not initializing `enter` Button object before calling `setOnClickListener`. do it as:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
// initilize Button here 
enter= (Button) findViewById(R.id.BUTTON_ID_IN_XML);
```